# Yarn workspaces with absolute path

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, npm-workspaces

I am using yarn 1.22.19, my `package.json` file contains

```
  "workspaces": [
    "/some/path/packages/*"
  ],
```

When I run `yarn install` it doesn't create symlink for the packages under that path. I also tried to delete `yarn.lock` but it didn't help.

The packages I want to link are not under the project's sub-tree.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defined workspaces must be descendants of the workspace root.

[source](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/)

> Workspaces must be descendants of the workspace root in terms of folder hierarchy. You cannot and must not reference a workspace that is located outside of this filesystem hierarchy.

So if your workspace root is located somewhere along the path `/some/path/packages/*`, for example at `/some/path`, then absolute paths should work. However, with this structure requirement there is no need to use absolute paths and you can define the workspaces as `packages/*`.

Comment: Thanks! What if I create a folder that is a descendant, and I symlink it to my packages and declare this new hacky folder as a workspace? I will give it a try maybe later this week. But maybe you already have a quick answer for that?